# How to free memory after fetching data via jdbc

Tags: java, sql, memory, jdbc, fetch

i am using spring jdbc on weblogic. And i set fetch size to 500 for fetching data from db more faster. But this causes memory problems. Here is an example:

http://webmoli.com/2009/02/01/jdbc-performance-tuning-with-optimal-fetch-size/

My question is how to free this memory? Running GC is not working, I guess it is not working because of connection is alive in the connection pool.

Code:

```
public List<Msisdn> getNewMsisdnsForBulkSmsId(String bulkSmsId,String scheduleId,final int msisdnCount) throws SQLException {
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate();
            jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(500);
            jdbcTemplate.setMaxRows(msisdnCount);
            jdbcTemplate.query("select BULKSMS_ID, ? as , STATUSSELECTDATE, DELIVERYTIME, ID, MESSAGE from ada_msisdn partition (ID_"+bulkSmsId+") where bulksms_id = ? and status = 0 and ERRORCODE = 0 and  SCHEDULEID is null for update skip locked", new Object[]{scheduleId,bulkSmsId}, MsisdnRowMapper.INSTANCE);

  //Also i tried to close connection and run gc, this does not free the memory too.
            //jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().close();
            //System.gc();

            return null;
}
```

when i set fetch size to 10, heap size is  12 MB
if i set fetch size to 500, heap size is 206 MB

Thanx

Comment: If you use a profiler you should be able to see why this memory is being retained.

Comment: it seems connection is allocating the memory, in my code no memory leaks : 60.9% - 206 MB - 561,359 alloc. org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query

Comment: If you set the fetch size to, say, 10, does the problem actually go away?

Comment: yes, but at this time query takes too long. Fetching data 500 by 500 is much more faster.

Answer (score 1):

Updates for added sample code, etc:

It sounds like you just need to use a value less than 500, but that makes me think you are returning a *lot* more data than your result set mapper is actually using.

Now that I see that you're storing *all* of the mapped results in a `List`, I would say that the problem seen with the fetch size is likely to be a secondary issue.  The combined memory space needed for the `List<Msisdn>` and a single group of fetched `ResultSet` rows is pushing you past available memory.

What is the value of `msisdnCount`?  If it's larger than 500, then you are probably using more memory in `list` than in the `ResultSet`'s 500 records.  If it's less than 500, then I would expect that the memory problem also occurs when you set the fetch size to `msisdnCount`, and the error would go away at some value between `min(msisdnCount, 500)` and 10.

Loading all of the results into a list and then processing them is a pattern that will very often lead to memory exhaustion.  The common solution is to use *streaming*.  If you can process each row as it comes in and *not* store all of the maps results in your `list`, then you can avoid the memory problems.

I don't see any streaming support in the Spring JDBC core package, but I'll update if I find it.

--

If that data in the rows you are retrieving is huge enough that fetching 500 rows will use up your heap, then you must either return less data per row or fetch fewer rows at a time.

You may find that you are storing the fetched rows somewhere in your code, which means that it's not the `ResultSet` using up your memory.  For example, you might be copying all of the rows to some collection instance.

I would look at the size of the data in each row and try to reduce unneeded columns that might contain large data types, then try simply loading the data and iterating through the results without doing your normal processing, which may be storing the data somewhere, to see how many rows you can load at a time with the memory you have.  If you're running out of memory fetching 500 rows, you must be pulling a lot of data over.  If you're not actually using that data, then you're wasting CPU and network resources as well as memory.

edit:  You may also want to set the cursor behavior to give your JDBC driver more help to know what it can throw away.  You can prepare your statements with ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY for example.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/ResultSet.html

Comment: i tried ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY and there is no effects

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer. i changed the code and i did not assign the query result to any variable. i profiled and see that the java.sql.Statement class allocating 206 MB. Then go to weblogic console and suspended connection pool and run the GC. I see that the memory turn back to normal. (206 MB deallocated). So, my question is how can i deallocate the memory without closing the connection.

Comment: If the GC returned the memory, then that indicates that the `java.sql.Statement` is not what is holding onto the memory.  I suspect is is the `List<Msisdn>` from from the evidence above unless "suspending" the connection pool means you closed the connections, which only happens with "forceSuspend()" and not "suspend()" according to the Weblogic documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jdbc/programming.html#1055751   If you can use the Spring `RowCallbackHandler` to process each row rather than make a `List`, you might be able reduce your memory usage.